# Find $\inf\limits_{p_{n}\in\bar{\prod}_{n}}\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|p_{n}(x)|$ where $p_{n}$: monic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, optimization, numerical-optimization, error-function

I want to find $M_{n}$ such that

> $$ M_{n}=\inf_{p_{n}\in\bar{\prod}_{n}}\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|p_{n}(x)|, $$
>   where $\overline{\prod}\limits_{n}$ is the set of all monic polynomial degree
>   $n$.

I was studying error analysis, and I have to minimize the $M_{n}$
to find the exact error.

---

For case $n=1$, $\max\limits_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|p_{1}(x)|=\max\left(|p_{1}\left(a\right)|,\ |p_{1}\left(b\right)|\right)$.

For case $n=2$, (I made short here) If $p_{2}\left(x\right)=x^{2}+mx+n$,
$\max\limits_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|p_{2}(x)|=\max\left(|-\frac{m^{2}}{4}+n|,\ |p_{1}\left(a\right)|,\ |p_{2}\left(b\right)|\right)$.
It is difficult for me to find $M_{2}$.

I need help here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need an exact answer for $M_n$, or are bounds okay?

Comment: @JoeyZou Bounds with respect to each $n$? If exists, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that for $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, the polynomial $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}T_n(x)$ minimizes $L^{\infty}$ norm, where $T_n$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial, and the wikipedia article on Chebyshev polynomials has a decent proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_.E2.88.9E-norm). Hence $M_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ for $[a,b] = [-1,1]$. The value for $M_n$ on other intervals $[a,b]$ can be obtained by scaling appropriately.